# The created gist index is not considered during the operation for 50m rows in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, gist-index

I am trying to write a new column based on the intersection of two polygon features which have 50m rows in one table, I have created the "gist" index before running them but it takes forever and I cannot get the result in Postgresql. The gist index is not used in the computation. How can I use the index for the operation?

The model is attached in the fiddle below,

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b3109f6892e2a9132c1aa137fdc109c2)

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_operation_geom ON public."Operation" USING gist (geom);

CREATE INDEX idx_operation_buffer ON public."Operation" USING gist (buffer);
CREATE INDEX idx_residential_geom ON public."Residential" USING gist (geom);

SELECT 
  ST_Intersection(ST_MakeValid(r.geom),o.buffer) AS intersection,   
  ST_Area(ST_Intersection(ST_MakeValid(r.geom),o.buffer))/ST_Area(r.geom)*100 
FROM public."Residential" r, public."Operation" o 
WHERE ST_Intersects(o.buffer,ST_MakeValid(r.geom));
```

I have tried to check the index using "Explain" but I am not sure how it works,

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: geometry = integer LINE 1: EXPLAIN
> SELECT * FROM public."Operation" where buffer = 2;

Any input will be very helpful.

Comment: Your buffer is of type `buffer geometry(polygon,4326),`You can't do an integer comparison, this is why your explain is failing. Fix this then you will see correct Explain output and you can go from there.

Comment: @VynlJunkie, Thank you for the explanation, but I am not sure how to use the Explain for the buffer geometry column, what can be done there ?

Comment: Haven't used geometry types. But look here. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html According to this you would need something like "buffer=((x1,y1),...)" In your same fiddle you even use it correctly. "buffer = ST_Buffer(geom::geography,100)::geometry;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index is not used because you have indexed `geom`

`CREATE INDEX idx_residential_geom ON public."Residential" USING gist (geom);`

but in the function that could call the index, you are using `ST_MakeValid(geom)`

Either you fix your geometries when you insert them, and you can drop the `st_makeValid()` statements in all other queries, or you would have to index the output of `ST_MakeValid()`

`CREATE INDEX idx_residential_valid_geom ON public."Residential" USING gist (ST_MakeValid(geom));`